# ATV3 Youtube Quality

Tags: video, appletv, settings, youtube, quality

I have a ***3rd generation   Apple TV*** that I'm trying to watch some ***YouTube*** tutorials on but the streaming quality is really low.
***How do I select a higher definition?*** I can't seem to find an option or setting for it.
The clip I'm watching right now actually started at around ***720p~1080p*** for the first ten seconds or so before reverting back to a blurry mess. It's obviously auto adjusting to the available bandwidth, just like it does in an ordinary browser, on an ordinary computer.
I don't mind if I have to wait for videos to load. I don't mind if it's not a *Full HD cinematic experience.* I just need it to be watchable. Surely there's something I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the default TV resolution of your Apple TV.

`Settings --> Audio&Video --> TV Resolution` and choose the resolution you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at the network connection and the Internet connection.  If neither of those are the issue, or (as with me) neither of those can be changed, the best I can suggest is to quickly pause the video near the beginning and wait a while, in hopes that your Apple TV will build a sufficient buffer at the desired resolution.  If the resolution downgrades before you can pause it, back out and try again.  I can't guarantee it'll work, but since there are no settings that would allow you to force a specific resolution with YouTube, that's the best I can suggest.

Sorry, [enzo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205709/1860), but that doesn't seem to be the issue.  He does seem to have the resolution set, otherwise he wouldn't get 10 seconds in the resolution he wanted and then a blurry mess afterward.  Unfortunately I have a similar problem that happens intermittently, and I suspect the problem is with my network connection between the Apple TV and my router (which, due to certain constraints, are not in the same room and so I have to use a wireless connection).  It may also be that the Internet connection is too slow to allow for the resolution he wanted.

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much what's happening. The old *pause, wait, buffer, play* trick was the first thing I tried, naturally. It doesn't seem to work the same as a typical web browser. What's weird is that; sometimes, even when it's stopping & starting, it keeps trying to playback at a decent resolution. Sometimes, it doesn't. Other times, even when it's mostly (or fully) loaded, it *doesn't* try to playback at a higher resolution. It's weird, like there's no logical pattern..